# How to creat form with get method and receive it

Tags: forms

I want to put a form in a page on my wordpress (in local). I have this form code :

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <h3>XML name :</h3>
    <input type="text" name="xml_id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I want to get the  `xml_id` in the same page (it's why : `action=""`). I've install Insert PHP plugin to insert this php code :

```
if (isset($_GET['xml_id']) and file_exists($_GET['xml_id']))
    {
        $link = 'http://localhost/wordpress/php/XML/display.php?xml_id='.$_GET['xml_id'];
        echo 'xml_id : '.$_GET['xml_id'].'<br />';
        echo $link.'<br />';
        $content = file_get_contents($link); 
        echo $content.'<br />';
    }
```

But, it doesn't works, and when it works, my page url is : `wordpress/?xml_id=XML`. Or I want something like that `wordpress/?page_id=1&xml_id=XML`.

Thanks.

Comment: if you're not posting to an external file, just add that code into the WordPress Template that has the form.

Comment: If I understand, I should add a template with my form in ?

Comment: How else are you adding your forum?

Comment: I want a form which is send an xml_id, i want to get this xml id which is sent to an API which is displayed XML data, in the same page (with the form) I get the XML data (API) with `file_get_contents();`

Comment: Ok, I would suggest adding it to a page template, both code. You can have it post to itself and once it posts you can get the values.

Comment: So, I need to creat a template with this 2 codes (form and php) ... And apply this template to a WP page ?

Comment: It's works, thanx you so much  Howdy_McGee